# Which database engines will allow me to GRANT/REVOKE on a specific column?

Tags: database-recommendation, feature-comparison, permissions

If I have a table with a single column of sensitive data, and I want to grant broad use of the table without exposing that one column, I know that I can create a VIEW that gives them access to all the non-sensitive columns. However, PostgreSQL allows you to grant column-level permissions in the form of

```
grant select (col1, ...coln) on table to role;
```

Are there other engines which provide this capability?

Comment: I just realized this should be a "community wiki" question, but I don't have enough rep to make it so...

Comment: sql server 2005, 2008... encrypting a column of data

Comment: not many things are CW anymore...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an SQL standard feature.  "Most" SQL implementations support it, including PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle, DB2, SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks, Peter - I don't have a copy of the specification, so I wasn't sure if it was covered there. I do happen to know that Firebird nee Interbase does NOT support this, and last time I tried it in MySQL, it didn't work (admittedly, that was a while ago in MySQL terms).

Answer (score 8):

SQL Server 2000, 2005, 2008 has this [capability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)

```
GRANT { ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
       | permission [ ( column [ ,...n ] ) ] [ ,...n ]
       [ ON [ class :: ] securable ] TO principal [ ,...n ] 
       [ WITH GRANT OPTION ] [ AS principal ]
```

**ADDED**

In SQL Server 2005, 2008 it is possible to [encrypt a column of data by using symmetric encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331.aspx), see *B.Symmetric encryption that includes an authenticator*. This variant returns [a NULL value, just as if the wrong key was used](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1760).

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle this is called [Column Masking](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/vpd.htm#i1014682).

Comment: That's not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

As @igor said SQL Server has that capability. I think back to Sybase times i.e. version 4.2.
I'm sure later (perhaps SQL-Server 7.0) I heard recommendation not to use that feature, but to use views or stored procedures instead,

Comment: sql2k, 2k5 new future: encrypting a column of data, it allows to return the same number of columns and NULL values in columns if you have not valid key.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can also perform [GRANTs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html#grant-column-privileges) and [REVOKEs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/revoke.html) on column privileges.

In fact, the mysql.columns_priv and information_schema.COLUMN_PRIVILEGES contain those privileges at that level.

mysql> show create table mysql.columns_priv\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: columns_priv
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `columns_priv` (
  `Host` char(60) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Db` char(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `User` char(16) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Table_name` char(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Column_name` char(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Column_priv` set('Select','Insert','Update','References') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Host`,`Db`,`User`,`Table_name`,`Column_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Column privileges'

mysql> show create table information_schema.column_privileges\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: COLUMN_PRIVILEGES
Create Table: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `COLUMN_PRIVILEGES` (
  `GRANTEE` varchar(81) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TABLE_CATALOG` varchar(512) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TABLE_SCHEMA` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TABLE_NAME` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `COLUMN_NAME` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `PRIVILEGE_TYPE` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `IS_GRANTABLE` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was usually done by creating a view and granting select on the view.

As I recall the harder question relates whether one can grant insert and/or update on the view in a meaningful way.  (Obviously the view must have all columns which would be required to maintain referential integrity constraints on the underlying table's schema).

However this is all academic for me.  I'd love to read some details from people who used views to manage insert/update access to a subset of columns using a view ... or how various vendor implement these columnar access grants.

Comment: Granting update and insert is very meaningful on a view. You can use triggers on views to make inserts and updates actually do something. I'm not necessarily saying that is advisable, but quite possible.